# How to remove space character in mobile view

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $('#name').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
  });
    $('#email').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
  });
    $('#phone').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
   });
    $('#location').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
  });
 });
</script>
```

This is my JS to remove Space Character, but its not support to mobile view.
   Can anyone help,
   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use [keyup](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress). keydown is deprecated now

Comment: when i use keyup, does n't work on both mobile view and windows view